# Android webview button may not be manipulated

Tags: java, android, android-webview, android-espresso

Running an espresso test that should press a button on a webview, but I'm getting a RuntimeException.

`onWebView()
        .withElement(findElement(Locator.XPATH, "//*[@id=\"submitBtn\"]"))
        .perform(webClick());`

I tried using ID and that wouldn't work either. The button has no text on it, just a picture of an arrow.

The first 4 lines of the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error in evaluationEvaluation: status: 11 value: {message=Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated} hasMessage: true message: Element is not currently visible and may not be manipulated
>   at android.support.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction$ExceptionPropagator.(Web.java:326)
>   at android.support.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.doEval(Web.java:291)
>   at android.support.test.espresso.web.sugar.Web$WebInteraction.perform(Web.java:258)

Comment: We could help more with more code.